# Different way of proving Maps into Product theorem

Tags: general-topology

Let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T_1})$ and $(\mathbb{R^2}, \mathcal{T_2})$ be standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$. Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be arbitrary topological space. If $f_1:X \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f_2:X \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous. Then if $g: X \to \mathbb{R^2}$ defined by $g(x) = (f_1(x), f_2(x))$ is also continuous.

I know one way to prove it is using product topology knowledge, by showing that $(\mathbb{R^2}, \mathcal{T_{\mathbb{R^2}}}) = (\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T_{\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}}})$. However, here is a hint that shows a different ways of proving without using product topology.

The hint is given as

> To prove, $g^{-1} (U)$ is open for every open set U in $\mathbb{R^2}$. Suppose $x \in g^{-1} (U)$. Find a open set$V_x$ of $X$ contains $x$ such that $V_x \subset g^{-1} (U)$. Write $g^{-1} (U)$ as a union of open sets $V_x$

I don't really know how to construct $V_x$, also, I don't see why the continuity of $f_1$ and $f_2$ fits into way of proving.

Comment: You will still have to use the product topology; see **Alex G.**’s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $U_1 \times U_2$ is some rectangular open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $g^{-1}(U_1 \times U_2) = f_1^{-1}(U_1) \cap f_2^{-1}(U_2)$. Of course, rectangular open sets form a basis for the topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$....

Comment: Not exactly.... My advice would be to go back to the definition of a basis for a topology. Make sure that you can prove that open rectangles form a basis for the topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$, as I've claimed. Then see if you can use this information to solve your problem.